# Stop Bootstrap accordion from scrolling

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using a function for smooth scrolling which seems to interfere with a FAQs accordion. When opening or closing any question tab that tab jumps to the top of the page. When leaving href* here

```
return this.find('a[href*="#"]').click(function(f) {
```

empty accordion works but smooth scrolling is disabled. Can't find a way to make both functions work simultaneously.

How can I prevent the FAQs tabs from jumping to the top and opening at their actual position without loosing the smooth scrolling?

```
(function(a, c) {
    var b = (function() {
        var d = c(a.documentElement),
            f = c(a.body),
            e;
        if (d.scrollTop()) {
            return d
        } else {
            e = f.scrollTop();
            if (f.scrollTop(e + 1).scrollTop() == e) {
                return d
            } else {
                return f.scrollTop(e)
            }
        }
    }());
    c.fn.smoothScroll = function(d) {
        d = ~~d || 600;
        return this.find('a[href*="#"]').click(function(f) {
            var g = this.hash,
                e = c(g);
            if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') === this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') && location.hostname === this.hostname) {
                if (e.length) {
                    f.preventDefault();
                    b.stop().animate({
                        scrollTop: e.offset().top
                    }, d, function() {
                        location.hash = g
                    })
                }
            }
        }).end()
    }
}(document, jQuery));
```

My HTML:

```
<div class="container">
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
    <div class="faqHeader">General questions</div>
    <div class="panel panel-default collapse">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">How fit and Experienced do I need to be for the Cycling Escapes?</a>
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
            <div class="panel-body">
                No, you don’t need to be a pro to ride our Cycling Escapes.
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a class="accordion-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo">How serious is the cycling?</a>
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel-body">
                Our Escapes are all about cycling, of course, but they are not stage races.
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a class="accordion-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseFourteen">Do I have to ride every day?</a>
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseFourteen" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel-body">
                Absolutely not. You can take as many days off as you want.
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a class="accordion-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree">Can you help me with my fitness preparation?</a>
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel-body">
                Sure we can.
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a class="accordion-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseFour">Is there a minimum age requirement?</a>
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseFour" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel-body">
                Yes, there is.
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a class="accordion-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseFive">How big are the groups?</a>
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseFive" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel-body">
                The groups are limited to 16 riders.
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a class="accordion-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseSix">Can I rent a bike and/or a GPS navigation system with you?</a>
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseSix" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel-body">
                At the moment we cannot offer rentals for bikes or GPS navigation system. Sorry.
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br>

    <div class="faqHeader">Accommodation</div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a class="accordion-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseSeven">Do I have to share my accomomodation with another rider?</a>
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseSeven" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel-body">
                All the prices of our Escapes are based on two people sharing a room.
                <br />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a class="accordion-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseEight">Is my bike safely stored when I'm not riding?</a>
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseEight" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel-body">
                There are a number of reasons why you should join us:
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
     <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a class="accordion-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseSixteen">Can you accommodate special dietary needs?</a>
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseSixteen" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel-body">
                We will do our very best to ensure that your dietary needs are met.
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <br>

    <div class="faqHeader">Prices</div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a class="accordion-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseNine">How much does it cost?</a>
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseNine" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel-body">
                You can find the cost for the individual Escapes in the 'ESCAPES' section of the website.
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a class="accordion-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTen">What is included in the Escape price?</a>
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseTen" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <ul>
                    <li>Accommodation for 7 or 10 nights in a 3 to 5 star hotel.</li>
                </ul> 
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a class="accordion-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThirteen">What is NOT included in the Escape price?</a>
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseThirteen" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <ul>
                    <li>Flights and/or train travels.</li>
                </ul> 
            </div>
        </div>
     </div>
     <br>
     <div class="faqHeader">Bookings</div>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a class="accordion-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseSeventeen">How do I book?</a>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseSeventeen" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel-body">
            Bookings can be made via the 'BOOKINGS' section of the website.
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a class="accordion-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseEighteen">Can I cancel my booking?</a>
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseEighteen" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel-body">
            Of course you can. You can cancel your booking at any time, but be aware that charges will apply and refunds are based on a sliding scale.
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="faqHeader">Travel/Transportation</div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a class="accordion-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseEleven">Can you help me with travel arrangements?</a>
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseEleven" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel-body">
                Unfortunately, we are not able to help you with any travel arrangements outside our Escapes.
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a class="accordion-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwelve">Do I need travel insurance?</a>
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseTwelve" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel-body">
                Yes, we strongly recommend that you take out a travel insurance as this is not included in any of our Escape prices.
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a class="accordion-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseFifteen">What travel documents do I need?</a>
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseFifteen" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel-body">
                A passport or an identity card is the most obvious.
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="faqHeader">Hey!</div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a class="accordion-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseNineteen">Why didn't you answer my question?</a>
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseNineteen" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel-body">
            Sorry. So many questions, so many answers...
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<style>
.faqHeader {
    font-size: 27px;
    margin: 15px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.panel-heading [data-toggle="collapse"]:after {
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';
    content: "\f138"; /* "play" icon; old icon: Glyphicons Halflings, e072*/
    float: right;
    color: #F58723;
    font-size: 30px;
    line-height: 27px;
    /* rotate "play" icon from > (right arrow) to down arrow */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
}

.panel-heading [data-toggle="collapse"].collapsed:after {
    /* rotate "play" icon from > (right arrow) to ^ (up arrow) */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
    transform: rotate(90deg);
    color: #454444;
}
```

Comment: Add your html. unless we would not be able to understand the problem

Comment: Sorry - that would definitely help. Done.

Answer (score 0):

You can add condition to check if its doesn't have the class `accordion-toggle` to continue with the other things in your function.

```
c.fn.smoothScroll = function(d) {
    d = ~~d || 600;
    return this.find('a[href*="#"]').click(function(f) {
        if(!$(this).hasClass('accordion-toggle')) {
            var g = this.hash,
                e = c(g);
            if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') === this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') && location.hostname === this.hostname) {
                if (e.length) {
                    f.preventDefault();
                    b.stop().animate({
                        scrollTop: e.offset().top
                    }, d, function() {
                        location.hash = g
                    })
                }
            }
        }
    }).end()
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks Shibi.